# How can I collect checked items from PHP array served in form?

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a form which builds the form items from a foreach loop and puts a checkbox by each item:

```
<form action="nextStep.php">
<?php
foreach ($children[0] as $myPage) {
$menuname = $info[$myPage]['label'];
echo '<input type="checkbox" id="'.$menuname.'" name="reveal_menu" value="no" unchecked><label for="'.$menuname.'">'.$menuname.'</label><br>';
}
?>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

As you can see, I start with each item unchecked.  What I would like to know is how I should build the `nextStep.php` script to create individual php variables that I can echo on the `nextStep.php` page after the user clicks the submit button?

Comment: Give the form a `name` and `method` attribute. Then on the next page reference the appropriate super global array `$_GET` or `$_POST` and use the variables as needed.

Comment: Try replacing `name="reveal_menu"` with `name="reveal_menu[]"` and do a `var_dump($_POST['reveal_menu'])` in PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must identify that this input is an array of values, by appending `[]` on the name:

```
echo '<input ... name="reveal_menu[]" ...>';
```

In nextStep.php:

```
foreach($_POST['reveal_menu'] as $checkbox)
   echo $checkbox;
```

EDIT to answer OP comment:

You would need to create an array to handle these values. But $_POST['reveal_menu'] itself is an array. So can access `$_POST['reveal_menu'][0]`, for example.

Keep in mind that `$_POST['reveal_menu']` is an array with **checked values ONLY** . The index `0` doesn't point for the first checkbox of your form, but for the first checkbox checked from your form.

Comment: This is great for being able to print each `$checkbox` item on the screen, but how can I then set them as individual PHP variables?

Answer (score 0):

Each item needs to have a unique value, probably the menuname, so you can tell which ones are checked, and the name needs to have `[]` operator appended to the end.

```
<form action="nextStep.php">
<?php
foreach ($children[0] as $myPage) {
$menuname = $info[$myPage]['label'];
echo '<input type="checkbox" id="'.$menuname.'" name="reveal_menu[]" value="$menuname" unchecked><label for="'.$menuname.'">'.$menuname.'</label><br>';
}
?>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When you loop through, you'll get an array of values.

```
<?php
  foreach($_POST['menuname'] as $v)
  {
    echo($v . 'Was checked.');
  }
?>
```